# Xcode Build Error

Tags: iphone, xcode

im completly a new on iphone development i have installed Xcode 3.1.4 on my mac os x power pc, i have created a Hello world program when i build and go the program it gives following error which i cant understand i have C# and java development background in which i never see this type of error message .

Error Message:

```
              Message                                  Location
```

File /untitled folder/Iphone Projects/Hello iphone/build | Line Location Tool:0

Please kindly any one explain me why this error occur and how i fix this error any help in this regard is greatly apprecialted thanks .

Comment: Hos did you create the Hello World program?

Comment: i follow steps given in this document:      http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/FeedEnclosure/utah.edu.1668842900.01668842919.1681195338/enclosure.pdf

Comment: hmmm, time for an intel Mac so you can run newer xcode, i am unsure of this erroryour getting though,is there nothing more in the console that gives any hints?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an Intel based Mac for iPhone development. A PPC machine isn't going to be able to do it.

Sorry :(